# How to get invoice data from Amazon SP-API for FBA orders regularly?

Tags: invoice, amazon-fba

Amazon requires sellers to upload invoices within 24 hours.

GET_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_INVOICING can be scheduled to get data but only for MFN orders. What's about AFN / FBA orders? GET_AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENTS_DATA_INVOICING can not be scheduled. Sounds strange for me. What is the right approach to get invoice data from new FBA orders regulary e.g. all 4 hours?